# PHP error: i have problem to fetch a specific user id in php

Tags: php

I designed a registration and login form now when i fetch my user profile from data base it show the last user detail not the one that i logged in. please help me how to fetch a specific user profile with it's registered email address. 
thank you very much and appreciated in advance.

Comment: what have you done? show your code

Comment: An [mcve] must entail code, database samples, and form input variables, etc.

Comment: <?php
                 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER by email LIMIT 1";
    $result = $con-> query($sql);
    if($result-> num_rows > 0) {
        
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td> ID: ". $row["id"] ."</td><br><td> User Name: ". $row["user"] . "</td><br><td> First Name: ". $row["first_name"] . "</td><br><td> Last Name: ". $row["last_name"] . "</td><br><td> Email: ". $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    
    ?>

Comment: Please edit your code into your question by using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58775175/edit)

Comment: It's for a user table, not for a login form. Refer to this link: [PHP - MySQL Login](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Let me correct my question. 1) when I login to my system and try to fetch my user information in profile.php it show the last registered ID it means I have registered couple users. Whenever I login with any of my user's email and password it shows the last registered ID. how to fix this and get specific user's information that I have entered his/her email and password into login system? your help will be appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the answer, Let me correct my question. 
1) when I login to my system and try to fetch my user information in profile.php it show the last registered ID it means I have registered couple users. Whenever I login with any of my user's email and password it shows the last registered ID. how to fix this and get specific user's information that I have entered his/her email and password into login system?
your help will be appreciated in advance.